# Python CSV reader to skip 9 headers

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

```
import os
import csv

def get_file_path(filename):
    currentdirpath = os.getcwd()
    file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    print(file_path)
    return(file_path)

path = get_file_path('Invoice-Item.csv')

def read_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for i in range(0, 9):            
            next(reader, None)        
        for row in reader:
            print(row[0])                   

read_csv(path)
```

I Looking for a technique to skip the 9 headers rather than the range function. Any help would be appreciated.  Below is a sample of the csv file

```
Summary Journal Entry,JE-00000060
Journal Entry Date,28/02/2015
Accounting Period,Feb-15
Accounting Period Start,1/02/2015
Accounting Period End,28/02/2015
Included Transaction Types,Invoice Item
Included Time Period,01/02/2015-09/02/2015
Journal Run,JR-00000046
Segments,
,
Customer Account Number,Transaction Amount
210274174,545.45
210274174,909.09
210274174,909.09
210274174,909.09
210274174,909.09
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip a fixed number of lines:

```
from itertools import islice

next(islice(reader, 9, 9), None)        
for row in reader:
    print(row[0])
```

The `islice()` object is instructed to skip 9 lines, then immediately stop without producing further results. It is itself an iterator, so you need to call `next()` on it still.

If you wanted to skip rows until the 'empty' row, that requires a different approach. You'd have to inspect each row and stop reading when you come across one that has only empty cells:

```
for row in reader:
    if not any(row):  # only empty cells or no cells at all
        break

for row in reader:
    print(row[0])
```

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> sample = '''\
... Summary Journal Entry,JE-00000060
... Journal Entry Date,28/02/2015
... Accounting Period,Feb-15
... Accounting Period Start,1/02/2015
... Accounting Period End,28/02/2015
... Included Transaction Types,Invoice Item
... Included Time Period,01/02/2015-09/02/2015
... Journal Run,JR-00000046
... Segments,
... ,
... Customer Account Number,Transaction Amount
... 210274174,545.45
... 210274174,909.09
... 210274174,909.09
... 210274174,909.09
... 210274174,909.09
... '''
>>> with io.StringIO(sample) as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         if not [c for c in row if c]:
...             break
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row[0])                   
... 
Customer Account Number
210274174
210274174
210274174
210274174
210274174
```

Note that you want to leave newline handling to the `csv.reader`; when opening your file set `newline=''`:

```
with open(filepath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Comment: is it workable using condition like WHILE since we only want to read part of the file. ie we want keep reading the line of the header until we reached
the blank line

Comment: @RicardLe you don't have a blank line; you have a row with one empty cell; the comma still counts. You didn't ask for an arbitrary count skip however, that is a *dudferent* problem.

Comment: The suggestion above i have tried but it won't skip over the 9 headers. am i missing something in between.

Comment: @RicardLe: ah, my mistake, you are using Python 3. Will correct as `filter(None, ...)` produces an iterable, not a list.

Comment: it hasn't worked for some reasons. it wont skip over the headers.

Comment: @RicardLe: sorry, I'm doing this in between things and the `not` got lost. I'll build a quick demo too to show it is now working correctly.

Comment: really appreciated your responses. I am able to reproduce your results using the text assigned to a variable SAMPLE. But if i changed it to 'Invoice-Item.csv' none was printed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using numpy, have a look at the skip_header argument in genfromtxt (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html )

```
import numpy as np     
r = np.genfromtxt(filepath, skip_header=9, names = ['account','amount'] , delimiter = ',')
print(r.account[0],r.amount[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider using pandas, `read_csv` makes reading files very straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=9)
```