# None column in csv (csv python module)

Tags: python, csv

An instrument create a CVS with this on the file header :

```
XLabel,Wavenumber
YLabel,Response
FileType,Single Beam
DisplayDirection,20300
PeakDirection,20312
0.000000,-1.149420,-1.177183,-1.174535
0.964406,-1.053002,-1.083787,-1.069919
1.928811,-0.629619,-0.652436,-0.628358
```

I want to read this value with cvs python module.

```
import csv
expfile='test.csv'
with open(expfile) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (i<4):
            i += 1
        else:
            print(row)
```

The output is :

```
{None: ['-1.025449', '-1.049773'], 'XLabel': '0.000000', 'Wavenumber': '-1.012466'}
{None: ['-1.256103', '-1.297049'], 'XLabel': '0.964406', 'Wavenumber': '-1.254550'}
{None: ['-0.722499', '-0.754096'], 'XLabel': '1.928811', 'Wavenumber': '-0.735748'}
```

It is easy to get `Xlabel` or `Wavenumber` value :

```
print(row['XLabel'])
```

But how can I get the `None` value?

Comment: See [Python CSV reader to skip 9 headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28603014) for a better way to skip a certain number of rows in a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `None` as the key:

```
print(row[None])
```

`None` is simply the value for the `restkey` argument to `DictReader()`, and `None` is the default. You could set it to something else. It is the key into which any *extra* columns that don't have a fieldname are collected into, and in your case the fieldnames are taken from the first row in the file, which has only two fields.

A better option would be to explicitly pass in some fieldnames:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=('Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4'))
```

because the first row of that format is not really suitable to act as labels for the columns past the first 5 rows. You can pick names that make sense for those 4 columns.

Note you'd have to skip *5* rows then, not 4. See [Python CSV reader to skip 9 headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603014/python-csv-reader-to-skip-9-headers) for an alternative technique where you don't have to keep a counter:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv

expfile='test.csv'

with open(expfile) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=('Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4'))
    next(islice(reader, 5, 5), None)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was trying row['None'] :x

Comment: @FrancoisDion: Added some more explanation as to what is going on, and a better alternative.

Comment: In case someone is confused by his linter warning him about `Unexpected type` when using `row[None]`, the issue is known and [has been recently fixed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/commit/5e907afac729787b414050d318daeb5a1c59d6a5).